# how to get only the attributes of all the models in a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection as shown below

```
window.courses = new Courses();
```

and some where in my code I am trying to access the attributes of the collection. I have used pluck to get only single attribute which is courseName

for example:

```
var courseName = window.courses.pluck('Name');
```

I can get all the courses names(single attribute) in my collection, but is there a way that I can get each items name and id from Courses collection,something like

```
var courseList = window.courses.pluck('Id','Name');
```

using below code

```
var courseList = window.courses;
```

I get all the extra details which I dont need,so can someone suggest how to get required attributes of all the models inside a collection

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Backbone [pluck function](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-96) only supports reading one attribute value.

You could write your own, for example:

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.pluckMany = function (attrs) {
    return _.map(this.models, function (model) {
        return _.pick(model.attributes, attrs);
    });
}

var courseList = window.courses.pluckMany(['Id', 'Name']);
```

NB: Untested code!

Comment: Actually I have almost the same approach, but i did an _.each on the colection and I called _.pick inside it,but is there any standard way to get the attributes of the models inside a collection

Comment: I don't think there's a standard version of the above. if you mean is there a standard way of getting the attributes of a model, then that's `attributes` or `toJSON()`.

Comment: thanks for the very quick answer.I belive backbone can have some direct approach to fetch needed attributes of all the models inside a collection

Comment: You could also make a variadic version by using `attrs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` and then `c.pluckMany('Id', 'Name')` could work. If you added a `_.isArray(attrs)` check then you could allow either calling style.